# removeAll operation on arraylist makes program hang

Tags: java, arraylist, removeall

I'm trying to read in from two files and store them in two separate arraylists. The files consist of words which are either alone on a line or multiple words on a line separated by commas.
I read each file with the following code (not complete):

```
ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();

FileInputStream fis;
fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);

Scanner scan = new Scanner(fis);

while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(scan.nextLine());
    input.useDelimiter(",");
    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        String md5 = scan.next();
        temp.add(md5);
    }
}
scan.close();    

return temp;
```

Each file contains almost 1 million words (I don't know the exact number), so I'm not entirely sure that the above code works correctly - but it seems to.

I now want to find out how many words are exclusive to the first file/arraylist. To do so I planned on using `list1.removeAll(list2)` and then checking the size of list1 - but for some reason this is not working. The code:

```
public static ArrayList differentWords(String fileName1, String fileName2) {
    ArrayList<String> file1 = readFile(fileName1);
    ArrayList<String> file2 = readFile(fileName2);

    file1.removeAll(file2);

    return file1;
}
```

My main method contains a few different calls and everything works fine until I reach the above code, which just causes the program to hang (in netbeans it's just "running").
Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: That sounds like an extremely heavy operation, that probably just takes forever to finish. I think you should reconsider your approach.

Comment: I think you meant `while (input.hasNext()) {`?

Comment: Using a `HashSet` instead of an `ArrayList` might speed this up.

Comment: `removeAll()` with 2 ArrayLists has quadratic runtime. 1.000.000^2 is a huge number. As user714965 suggested, use a `Set`, it will speed things up immensely.

Comment: Your current code adds the WHOLE line to the List, read my answer.

Comment: ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();
should be ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: @JordanBorisov not if he/she is using Java 7 (diamond inference).

Comment: @user714965 and jlordo Thanks so much. I changed it to a hashset and now it seems to be doing stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using `input` in

```
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(scan.nextLine());
  input.useDelimiter(",");
  while (scan.hasNext()) {
    String md5 = scan.next();
    temp.add(md5);
  }
}
```

I think you meant to do this:

```
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(scan.nextLine());
  input.useDelimiter(",");
  while (input.hasNext()) {
    String md5 = input.next();
    temp.add(md5);
  }
}
```

but that said you should look into `String#split()` that will probably save you some time:

```
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
  String line = scan.nextLine();
  String[] tokens = line.split(",");
  for (String token: tokens) {
    temp.add(token);
  }
}
```

Comment: The thing that's costing time here is `file1.removeAll(file2);` where `file1` and `file2` are huge `ArrayList`s. Your solution probably wouldn't even save a whole second, if it saves time at all.

Comment: In the question it hangs, meaning it's not working, probably because of what I pointed out? When his/her program works, he/she can then ask why it is slow.

Comment: From the OP: *"I'm not entirely sure that the above code works correctly - but it seems to"*. Here's where it goes wrong: first test your program on a small input set and make sure it is **correct**! Clearly, using the **wrong `Scanner`** makes any attempt to "optimize the cost" futile. As for the actual optimization, using `HashSet`s in place of `ArrayList`s reduces the complexity of `removeAll` from `O(n^2)` to `O(n)`, which should result in a considerable speed-up.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens you're right, I should've done that first. I'm not used to working with such large lists.

Comment: @Djon your first fix added like 20-30 seconds to each call, but the String.split did the trick. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @GeorgeWChubby It did because you were properly parsing the words in the lines, but I'm glad I could help. (Make sure to use a Set too as Mattias explained.)

Answer (score -1):

try this :

```
for(String s1 : file1){
    for(String s2 : file2){
        if(s1.equals(s2)){file1.remove(s1))}
    }
}
```

Comment: This is equivalent to an naive unoptimized `removeAll` (i.e. disregarding optimizations using the collection type such as `Set`s). Also, it will fail with a `ConcurrentModificationException` because you're modifying `file1` inside the loop directly (instead of using `Iterator.remove`).